# How to automate factory design pattern in swift?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I want to automate this piece of code:

```
    let objectType = json["object"]["type"].stringValue;

    switch objectType {
        case "Message":
            activity.item = MessageLib.make(json["object"]) as! MessageItem;
        default:
        ()
    }
```

I want to make an object based on its type. But I don't want to write a new case for each new ObjectType. I just want to make a new object class.
OBJECTTYPEItem

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: I want it to decide what subclass to use for itself.

Comment: I want to remove the switch case

Comment: But the mapping inevitably has to specified somewhere

Comment: Else how would your code figure what to do with each type. There's nothing wrong with doing it this way. If you wan't you can use enums to ensure that all cases have been handled.

Comment: I do that myself. That's not the problem. MessageItem and MessageLib are made by me. I want to add more objects like NoteItem and NoteLib, DocumentItem and DocumentLib, etc. That's my job. But I want the main class to decide which to use, based on its type.

Comment: I still don't get what exactly you need. Could you say what you want that you could do in Java or Objective-C that you can't figure out how to do in Swift ?

Comment: I need something like eval in php or javascript.

Comment: Tough luck mate. Swift is strongly typed with compile time type inference. Stuff like won't work in swift. You can drop down into Objective C and use the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is not a pure swift class and inherits somewhere from `NSObject`, I would recommend using something like `NSClassFromString` and creating object from it.

```
let objectType = json["object"]["type"].stringValue;
var classType = NSClassFromString(objectType)
var classVariable = classType()
```

You can typecast this class to any of your classes using

```
var myClassType = classType as! MyClass.type
```

Comment: For this the class has to be an Objective-C class or a Swift class tagged @objc . Will this work with a pure swift class ?

Comment: How can you call its methods? Swift won't know its methods or return type!

Comment: @SamhanSalahuddin Yeah it won't work with pure swift classes.

Comment: One of the things I don't like about Swift. The lack of dynamism , KVC . :D

Comment: @XIII At some point or another, you will definitely have to type cast this class to your custom class, using a switch method or something else. Because you would need to call functions/ set variables on this class.

Comment: @iosDev82 you are right. I think the best way is to stick with the switch case. :|

Answer (score 0):

This is my factory which follows @Shamas S directions, including some added code to make it of more general use. The compiler gives no error if ContentItemFactory does not inherits from NSObject, but you have to import the Foundation framework to use `NSClassFromString`

In my case all the created class-objects are subclasses of "ContentItem" class, which is initialized by `init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any])`, so I have to use the `required` keyword before that initializer.

```
import Foundation
class ContentItemFactory {

    class func create(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]) -> ContentItem{

        if let objectType = dictionary["type"] as? String{
            let namespace = (Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
            let myClass = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(objectType)") as! ContentItem.Type
            return myClass.init(fromDictionary:dictionary)
        }
        return ContentItem.init(fromDictionary: dictionary)
    }
}

class ContentItem {
    required init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){

    }
}
```